# Picasa "blog this" choking on 'cookie' problems

Tags: cookies, picasa

Whenever I click on the "blog this" link in Picasa, it throws up a window complaining about cookies (helpfully in German, because Google thinks that everyone in Switzerland reads German). A rough translation (from Google also) is included below. I've done everything it suggests, but on inspection, it's totally useless.

As far as I can tell, Picasa uses it's own embedded version of IE (it shows up as IE7 at http://www.thismachine.info/, whereas I have IE9 installed). So changing cookie settings in IE9 isn't going to help.

Has anyone else even see this problem? Any ideas? Or maybe your Google-fu is better than mine?

> **Google has detected a problem with your cookie settings**
>
> **Enable Cookies** Make sure that cookies are enabled. Follow these
>   cookies to enable browser-specific instructions.
>
> **Clearing cache and cookies** If you have cookies enabled and the problem
>   still exists then empty the browser cache and delete cookies.
>
> **Customize privacy settings** If the problem is clearing the cache and
>   deleting cookies does not, adjust the privacy settings of your
>   browser. If this is set to "High", manually add www.google.com to your
>   list of allowed sites. More information

Answer (score 0):

Never really found a satisfying answer to this.

Sometimes a Back (backspace) or refresh (F5) works, other times I have to resort to loading 'manually' from a browser.